# Comparing two inputs to data set to return single output

Tags: excel, vba, compare

I require some help in a programming process rather than a program itself (if code is available then this would be even better!). I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns (ID,CS, part), I am trying to setup a user-form where if ID and CS are specified as inputs, the closest value set of these returns a part (or a number of parts which have close ID and CS values) for example, data is:

**ID**///**CS**///**Part**

10///4.2///PN1

12///5.7///PN038

103.43///5.7///PN99

And user inputs ID=11.27, CS=4, the program returns PN1 as this is the "closest" combination.

I have attempted to set this up myself by looping through all CS's initially and finding one just above and below the required value and exact if it is present in the data, then the ID's for these CS's are examined just as for the CS by looking at the ID just above, just below and exact if present and then outputing all 9 values into a listbox however, this got very confusing and messy therefore, I was looking for a more elegant solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Sub test()

'leastDeviation changed to 4447 as its maximum value is 4446. (61.75*8^2+494)
 leastDeviation = 4447
 lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 For rowCheck = 1 To lastRow
     'squared to eliminate sign
     deviation = 61.75 * (inputID - Cells(rowCheck, "A")) ^ 2 + (inputCS - Cells(rowCheck, "B")) ^ 2
     If deviation < leastDeviation Then
         closest = rowCheck
     End If
 Next rowCheck
 closestPart = Cells(closest, "C")
 End Sub`
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is amazing and works much better than what I had put together. Is there any way of setting it such that the deviation in ID is not scored the same as CS? By that I mean, where CS is slightly more critical in terms of small deviations? This is because ID ranges anywhere between 6-500 and CS is around 1-9.

Comment: You could try weighting the deviations by their ranges. So the ID ranges from 1-9; a difference of 8. And the CS ranges from 6-500 which is a difference of 494, making the ratio of the ranges 8:494. 494/8 is 61.75 so we could get away with saying that a deviation of 1 in ID is 61.75 times more volatile than the same in CS; check what I've changed above.
It also depends on what your purpose is; if the inputted IDs and CS's are meant to represent means then you could do a similar thing with the standard deviation statistic.